# Stab my head off

Tags: riddle, rhyme

I can dance and swirl in romantic ballrooms

But I'm just as good a companion in the gloom.

Dizzying, flying far above the ground,

But I'll always land, safe and sound.

My best friend can be cheap and overdone

But without him, I'm rarely fun.

Time doesn't matter to me. It does for my cousins.

I can look (a bit) like one of them, but actually, he's Russian.

Though my brothers and I were born of the same parents in the same year,

Our lives will end with a fist around our necks, our heads ripped off in cheer.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think it's

> Champagne

I can dance and swirl in romantic ballrooms

> Champagne is common in those glamourous events

But I'm just as good a companion in the gloom.

> ...but anyone can drink it perfectly in the dark

Dizzying, flying far above the ground,

> When one opens a champagne, it will often explode

But I'll always land, safe and sound.

> ...but of course, gravity will bring it back

My best friend can be cheap and overdone

> I think this refers to the carbon dioxide inside. It is a cheap chemical, and one can easily put too much into a beverage

But without him, I'm rarely fun.

> but they can easily put too few, too, and that'll take the sparkle off the drink

Time doesn't matter to me. It does for my cousins.

> Aging is important for wine, but not as much for champagne

I can look (a bit) like one of them, but actually, he's Russian.

> I guess there's some specific Russian wine type that looks like champagne?

Though my brothers and I were born of the same parents in the same year,

> This refers to the source grapevine

Our lives will end with a fist around our necks, our heads ripped off in cheer.

> Opening the bottle, again, you grab it by its neck and pull the "head" off

Finally, the title

> We use a corkscrew to stab the...head off

Comment: We use a corkscrew? Eh?